# electric pair of any length, using AUCTex

Tags: auctex, electric-pair-mode

According to https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AutoPairs the package `smartparens` supports an electric pair of any length for example `\{`.

My question about the possibility that the built-in `electric-pair-mode` can do it. I tried this without success:

```
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook
              (lambda ()
                (define-key LaTeX-mode-map "\\{" 'electric-pair)))
```

Comment: AUCTeX doesn't play nicely with `electric-pair-mode`, this minor mode is actually disabled in AUCTeX if `LaTeX-electric-left-right-brace` is non nil.

Comment: @giordano if you have a solution purely based on auctex or any other suggestion (e.g. using another package) I would be grateful. Otherwise I am happy to use smartparens.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AUCTeX has a bultin support for [pairing braces](https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex.html#Braces), and `\{...\}` is in the default set of supported braces.  In order to enable this feature, just set [`LaTeX-electric-left-right-brace`](https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex.html#index-LaTeX_002delectric_002dleft_002dright_002dbrace) to non nil, either with customize interface (<kbd>M-x</kbd> `customize-variable` <kbd>RET</kbd> `LaTeX-electric-left-right-brace` <kbd>RET</kbd>) or by adding the following line to your init file:

```lisp
(setq LaTeX-electric-left-right-brace t)
```

This is much more advanced than any other generic mode for pairing braces, because it is able to do something like this:

```tex
\Bigl\{  →  \Bigl\{\Bigr\}
```

Comment: If one likes to temporary disable inserting electric braces, one use `C-q` or `C-u 1` before typing `{`, `(`, `[`, etc.

Comment: I enable smartparens-mode globally, but since LaTeX-electric-left-right-brace is more useful for tex file,  so I disable sp using (turn-off-smartparens-mode) inside LaTeX-mode-hook, but sp will always be triggered somehow after some time of editing tex file, and I don't know how to completely in LaTeX-mode. Any idea?

Comment: No, I don't use smart parens, sorry.